# What's $\lim_{x \to 0} 2^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{x-1}{x-2}$?

Tags: limits

I need to find the following limit
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \left\{f(x) = 2^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{x-1}{x-2}\right\}
\end{align}
After plotting this thing I got $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = \infty$.
I am not too sure, however, how one would show it analytically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The factor $(x-1)/(x-2)$ is well behaved around zero, the problem is $2^{1/x}$, note that

$$
2^{1/x} = e^{\ln 2^{1/x}} = e^{\ln 2/x}
$$

and remember that

$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty} e^x = +\infty ~~~~\mbox{and}~~~ \lim_{x\to -\infty} e^x = 0
$$

With these two things together

$$
\lim _{x\to 0^+}2^{1/x} = \lim _{x\to 0^+} e^{\ln2 / x} = \lim _{y\to +\infty} e^{y\ln 2 } = +\infty
$$

whereas

$$
\lim _{x\to 0^-}2^{1/x} = \lim _{x\to 0^-} e^{\ln2 / x} = \lim _{y\to -\infty} e^{y\ln 2 } = 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Change variable as $x\rightarrow\frac{1}{x}$ and you will get
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}2^x\frac{1-x}{1-2x}
$$
and you should see the result.

Comment: Should you not distinguish between the left and right limit, i.e. a positive and a negative value for x? The former results in $+\infty$, the latter in $0$.

Comment: Yes, you get different values running from left or right remembering that $2^x$ run to zero for $x\rightarrow -\infty$ and to infinity for $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: I have not got into deeper because this approach has been exploited thoroughly in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x \to 0}2^{\frac{1}{x}}\times \underbrace{\left( \frac{x-1}{x-2}\right)}_{\text{No indeterminacy here}}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{2}2^{\frac{1}{x}} $$

Now put for $x \to 0^+$ i.e. $x=0+h$

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{1}{2}2^{\frac{1}{h}} \longrightarrow 2^{\infty} \longrightarrow \infty$$

Now put for $x \to 0^-$ ,$x=0-h$

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{1}{2}2^{\frac{1}{-h}}\longrightarrow 2^{-\infty} \longrightarrow 0$$

Answer (score 1):

You can split the calculation:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}2^{1/x}=\infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}2^{1/x}=0$$

so the above limit doesn't exist.

Also,

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-1}{x-2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

and then (using that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\cdot g(x)=\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\cdot \lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)$), we get:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}2^{1/x}\frac{x-1}{x-2}=\infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}2^{1/x}\frac{x-1}{x-2}=0$$

so the limit doesn't exist.